# memory usage grows rapidly when using multiprocessing and sqlalchemy objects

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, multiprocessing

this is my first question on SO, so please be patient. I did some searching here and there but couldn't find solution for my problem even though there is written a lot on topic of multiprocessing and memory.
My program uses sqlalchemy objects that are connected with another objects within database (article has some entities and so on), in one step I need to take score for each pair of articles, this part has huge computational cost. I wanted to use multiprocessing to speed things up (for 1000 articles it takes 210 minutes to complete).
Original single process version consumes cca 750 MB of memory and sticks to that amount, after forking into 4 processes, each process's memory grows with time and reaches over 1.5 GB. What can cause such memory consumption? I tried to spawn processes before loading articles from DB, also passing less data to the mapped function but with little result. All the data coming in the function are not altered inside the function.

Problematic piece of code:

```
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
# loading articles into self.articles, this becomes dictionary with article ids as keys
# doing some more computing, not important AFAIK
scores = pool.map(articlePairScoreWrapper, [(article1,  # instance of sqlalchemy mapped class containing references to another DB records
    article2, 
    article1.rssRecord.date,  # datetime object
    article2.rssRecord.date, 
    self.dateThreshold,  # small integer
    self.tfIdfCorpus[self.dbGensimMapper[article1.id]],  # this is quite short dictionary
    self.tfIdfCorpus[self.dbGensimMapper[article2.id]], 
    self.quotationsArt[article1.id],  # short list of strings, often empty
    self.quotationsArt[article2.id], 
    self.weights  # dictionary with 3 small items
    ) for article1, article2 in itertools.combinations(self.articles.values(), 2)])
```

articlePairScoreWrapper only returns value of articlePairScore(*args)

I hope, that I didn't forget about anything and wasn't too verbose as well, thank you for your responses

EDIT:

ps -l -y output while running, had to kill it shortly after because of too much swapping

```
S   UID   PID  PPID  C PRI  NI   RSS    SZ WCHAN  TTY          TIME CMD
S  1000 16723 11247 59  80   0 670736 322767 futex_ pts/13 00:01:48 Article_cluster
S  1000 16734 16723  5  80   0 1414648 396561 futex_ pts/13 00:00:09 Article_cluster
S  1000 16735 16723  5  80   0 1310716 377368 futex_ pts/13 00:00:09 Article_cluster
S  1000 16736 16723  5  80   0 1327292 374276 futex_ pts/13 00:00:09 Article_cluster
D  1000 16737 16723  2  80   0 965584 287491 sleep_ pts/13 00:00:05 Article_cluster
```

although, I managed to optimize the original function and it is working quite well without multiprocessing, so no need to solve this

Comment: I suspect that it has something to do with the parent memory pool being copied into the child processes

Comment: Just to be sure, can you post the relevant ps output while your code is running with the 4 childs

Comment: Hi Martino, thank you for your response, I added ps output, but I am not sure about the benefit of it. I had quite the same idea with copying the memory, but each process having twice the amount of memory than the original one suggested some other problem as well. Quite interesting is fact, that mapping great number (by great I mean about 10^7) of inputs to some function using `pool.map()` increases memory wildly as well. On the other hand, I managed to solve the problem without using multiprocessing, so probably no need to waste time with this. Thanks again for your response.

Comment: If I recall correctly, when any of the child tries to alter the parent objects, the memory cannot be shared and must be copied entirely to the child process. I think this is the case and apparently the values from `ps` confirm it, each child consumes roughly double of the parent (parentmem+childmem)

Comment: I am not sure, why should child process consume double of the parent, in the beginning (process created by `Pool`, not function mapped), it shares data of the parent (the reason why I created the processes at the top of the function, before loading data), when it tries to alter something (and the function doesn't alter anything, only computes) it is copied into its own memory, so in the end I would expect, that child could have same amount of memory as the parent + memory needed for its own variables and that it will be steady for each iteration, which is not and grows. Is it correct?

Comment: It's plausible, yet I cannot confirm it without trying it myself :) Anyway the child will have the parent's memory size + its own private set